# How to get cookies with WGET, CURL, or python

Tags: python, curl, cookies, wget, urllib

I want to grab all the cookies a website send to the user when someone visit a web. I run WGET with the following configuration:

```
wget --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies cookies.txt www.google.com
```

On cookies.txt I can see:

```
.google.com TRUE    /   FALSE   1603387864  NID 202=[SUPER_LONG_UGLY_VALUE]
.google.com TRUE    /   TRUE    1590168664  1P_JAR  2020-04-22-17
```

But when I check on the browser the cookies that are sent to my machine, I can see around 20.

I have also tried using cookie-jar on python3 and urllib, but same result.

Is there any way to get those 20 cookies using WGET or CURL or Python?

Comment: Those other cookies could be the result of javascript execution. In that case, you would need to use something like selenium.

Comment: @jordanm I tried this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path], but I still have the same two cookies. Do you have any other tip?